# How to perform set subtraction on arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, set-operations

What's the simplest way to perform a set subtraction given two arrays in C#? Apparently this is [dead easy](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Array/ArraySubtractionandDifference.htm) in Ruby. Basically I just want to remove the elements from array `a` that are in array `b`:

```
string[] a = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
string[] b = new string[] { "two", "four", "six" };
string[] c = a - b; // not valid
```

`c` should equal `{ "one", "three" }`. `b - a` would yield `{ "six" }`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're using Linq, you can use the [Except operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) like this:

```
string [] c = a.Except(b).ToArray();
```

**Edit:**  CodeInChaos makes a good point. If `a` contains duplicates, it will remove any duplicates as well. The alternative to make it function exactly like the Ruby version would be this:

```
string [] c = a.Where(x=>!b.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that this will only return unique elements. So if you have one element twice in `a` it will only keep the first one.

Comment: Excellent, thanks--don't know how I missed that. Guess the naming just threw me off.

Comment: The alternative will remove duplicates!

Comment: Note that your alternative code is `O(a.Length*b.Length)`. To make it fast you need to construct a `HashSet<T>` out of `b`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - True, but I'm not trying to optimize, just show the syntax. Ideally you would write your own extension `ExceptLikeRuby` or something that would wrap this functionality.

Comment: @Keltez Your alternative will still remove duplicates. If you have { 'A', 'A' } - {'A'} == { }

Comment: @xanatos - That's the proper behavior, to remove all elements from A that are in B. On the other hand my alternative will do {'B','B'} - {'A'} = {'B','B'}

Answer (score 4):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Minus<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> elements = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    foreach (var el in enum2)
    {
        int num = 0;
        elements.TryGetValue(el, out num);
        elements[el] = num + 1;
    }

    foreach (var el in enum1)
    {
        int num = 0;
        if (elements.TryGetValue(el, out num) && num > 0)
        {
            elements[el] = num - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return el;
        }
    }
}
```

This won't remove duplicates from enum1. To be clear:

1. { 'A', 'A' } - { 'A' } == { 'A' }
2. { 'A', 'A' } - { 'A' } == { }

I do the first, Enumerable.Except does the second.

Comment: `elements.Remove` should be `elements.Contains`

Comment: @Keltex, the idea is that you want to remove it because it's been counted already. However, I believe it should be a `List` instead of a `HashSet` because it otherwise won't account for `{a, a, a}` - `{a, a}` = `{a}`.

Comment: No, it should be a Dictionary, so I'm still in a O(m * log(n)) (technically probably O((m + 1) * log(n)) )

Comment: With Linq, you can just do `var elements = enum2.GroupBy(el => el).ToDictionary(elg => elg.Key, elg => elg.Count());`.