# How to delete a numbers from Array that contained in another Array?

Tags: c#, arrays

How I can delete a numbers from Array “a” that contained in Array “b”?

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] b = {3, 9};
```

Comment: you can see something similar here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058609/how-to-perform-set-subtraction-on-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot delete items from an array. What you can do is create another array that contains the items from `a` except the items in `b` and assign it to variable `a` like this:

```
a = a.Except(b).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy b into a list, and then delete elements from it.

```
List<int> bList = new List<int>();
bList.AddRange(b);
foreach (int check in a)
{
    if (bList.Contains(check))
    {
        bList.Remove(check);
    }
}
b = bList.ToArray();
```