# String Arrays in c#. Removing elements from one string array which are their in another string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two string arrays -

```
            string[] One = new string[3];

            One[0] = "Pen";          
            One[1] = "Pencil";          
            One[2] = "card";
```

and,

```
            string[] Two = new string[2];

            Two[0] = "card";          
            Two[1] = "drive";
```

Now, I want a new string array from these two, such that the final result does not contain any element of the Two array. i.e. it should have, "Pen", "Pencil" only.

Comment: Like Union method in c#, is there any similar method which can be used here ??

Comment: Yes, you can use linq Except method. One.Except(Two).ToArray()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform set subtraction on arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058609/how-to-perform-set-subtraction-on-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq -

```
var res = One.Where(x => Two.Find(x) == null);
```

Or even better:

```
        string[] One = new string[3];

        One[0] = "Pen";
        One[1] = "Pencil";
        One[2] = "card";
        string[] Two = new string[2];

        Two[0] = "card";
        Two[1] = "drive";

        var res = One.Except(Two);
```

Answer (score 5):

This simple linq query can give you result.

```
var res = One.Except(Two);
```

Further, if in case you need to ignore case, use overload version of above method as:

```
var res = One.Except(Two, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

OR, Equivalently.

```
var res  = One.Where(x=>!Two.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is one of the easy way using linq. If you want to ignore case, then you can use the overloaded method: "One.Except(Two, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)"

Comment: Thanks for your ans I will Update It as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like non-intersect

```
         string[] One = new string[3];

            One[0] = "Pen";          
            One[1] = "Pencil";          
            One[2] = "card";

        string[] Two = new string[2];

            Two[0] = "card";          
            Two[1] = "drive";

        var nonintersectOne = One.Except(Two);   
        foreach(var str in  nonintersectOne)
           Console.WriteLine(str);

        // Or if you want the non intersect from both
        var nonintersectBoth = One.Except(Two).Union(Two.Except(One)).ToArray();
        foreach(var str in  nonintersect)
           Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output 1:

> Pen
>
> Pencil

Output 2:

> Pen
>
> Pencil
>
> drive

Comment: Quite right, updated accordingly. Leaving the secondary solution for anyone who might want it.

Comment: Please don't make the answer confusing by adding in superfluous content.